# Angular Service - Passing 'this'

Tags: angularjs, service, scope, this

I am attempting to use an external function to reduce repeating standard $http call code within an angular service and am having what I think are scope/this issues.  The question is, how do I amend the service so that I can make use of 'this' from myService in calls to the apiGet function

Example service code:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {

    function myService() {
        this.UID;
        this.stuff;
        this.things;
    }

    myService.build = function() {
        return new myService();
    };

    myService.prototype.setUID = function(UID) {
        this.UID = UID;
    };

    // key part of problem code - have tried this:
    myService.prototype.getStuff = apiGet.apply(this,[$http,'stuff',this.UID]);
    // and this:
    myService.prototype.getThings = apiGet($http,'things',this.UID);
}]);
```

Example external function code:

```
function apiGet($http,collection,UID) {
return function() {
    return $http({
            method:  'get',
            url:     '/php/'+collection+'/'+UID,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });

    }
};
```

The last lines of the service are what I am having trouble with - if I 'hardcode' a UID into the function call then the service works fine, but when I use 'this' within the arguments to call the function then UID appears as 'undefined'.

I've key bits of the controller code are below - I instantiate the service and then use the setUID method to apply the UID.  After that other methods within the controller call the myService.getStuff methods, etc.

```
    this.svc = new MyService();
    this.svc.setUID(UID);
```

It all works perfectly, including the 'this' bit if I don't use the apiGet function and just create the service method long hand, i.e:

```
    myService.prototype.getStuff = function() {
        return $http({
            method:  'get',
            url:     'php/stuff/'+this.UID,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }       
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
```

BTW, I'm pretty new to angular and my head is spinning slight with respect to scope, $scope, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out, thanks to @Henry suggestion around re-factoring my services to make them simpler.

API function code is as follows:

```
function apiGet($http,collection,UID) {
    return $http({
        method:  'get',
        url:     '/php/'+collection+'/'+UID,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

Sample service code:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.factory('myService',['$http',function($http) {

    var myService = {
        setUID        : setUID,
        getStuff      : getResources,
        getThings     : getThings
    };
    return myService;

    function setUID(UID) {
        this.UID = UID    
    };

    function getStuff() {
        return apiGet.apply(this,[$http,'stuff',this.UID]);            
    };

    function getThings() {
        return apiGet.apply(this,[$http,'things',this.UID]);            
    };
}]);
```

This now works perfectly, and I can re-use the apiGet function across multiple services very simply

Answer (score 0):

Angular services are singletons, there's no need to deal with instance/prototypes directly (since only 1 copy will be created).

```js
angular
.module('myApp')
.factory('myService', ['$http', 'baseService', function($http, httpGet) {
  var uid; //to be set by setUID;
  var myService = Object.create(baseService); //'inherits' from baseService
  angular.extend(myService, {  //extends with custom methods
    build: build,
    setUID: setUID,
    getStuff: _.partial(httpGet, $http, "stuff"),
    getThings: _.partial(httpGet, $http, "things"),
  });
  return myService;
  
  function build (){...}
  function setUID (){...}
  function getStuff (){...}
  function getThings (){...}
   
}]);
```

To use this service, simply inject the service and you'll have access to:

```
myService.getThings(this.uid); //calls httpGet($http, 'things', UID);
myService.getStuff(this.uid); //calls httpGet($http, 'stuff', UID);
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, useful to know (I'm still getting used to the concepts), however I don't think it answers the fact that I want to use a common function across a number of the service methods

Comment: I've updated it to show how to extend from a baseService. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something as I don't think it answers the question - the key thing is that the `getStuff` and `getThings` methods use the same code to make a call to a REST API, but I want to remove duplication of code between those methods by having the `apiGet` function (or similar) that I can just use the service method to call with the appropriate parameters/arguments based upon properties of the service (i.e. the UID).

Comment: Could I use `getStuff: getAPI('stuff',this.UID)` and `getThings: getAPI('things',this.UID)` and then have `function getAPI (collection,UID){...}` ?

Comment: I've updated myService to inject httpGet and wrapped partials around httpGet to pre-fill some info.